# Python Requests - Azure Graph API Authentication

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to access the Azure AD Graph API using the Python requests library. My steps are to first get the authorization code. Then, using the authorization code, I request an access token/refresh token and then finally query the API.

When I go through the browser, I am able to get my authorization code. I copy that over to get the access token. However, I've been unable to do the same with a Python script. I'm stuck at the part where I get the authorization code.

My script returns a response code of 200, but the response headers don't include that field. I would've expected the new URL with the code to be in the response headers. I would have also expected a response code of 301.

Does anyone know why my response headers don't have the auth code? Also, given the auth code, how would I pull it out to then get the access/refresh tokens using Python?

My code is below:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (USERNAME, PASSWORD)

# Authorize URL
authorize_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/authorize' % TENANT_ID
# Token endpoint.
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token' % TENANT_ID

payload = { 'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
          }

request = s.get(authorize_url, json=payload, allow_redirects=True)
print request.headers
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are implementing with [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) via python requests. As the flow shows, the response of the request of `authorize_url` will redirect to a SSO page of your AD tenant.  After your user login on, it will redirect to the location which set in  `redirect_uri` with `code` as the URL parameters. E.G. `http://localhost/?code=AAABAAAAiL...`
And your code seems cannot simply display a html page with JavaScript allowed, so it will not redirect to the login on page.

So you can refer to @ theadriangreen’s suggestion to implement with a python web server application.

Otherwise, you can refer to [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python#microsoft-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-python), which is a python package for acquiring access token from AD and can be easily integrated in your python application.